# Spark's int96 time type

Tags: datetime, apache-spark, parquet

When you create a timestamp column in spark, and save to parquet, you get a 12 byte integer column type (int96); I gather the data is split into 6-bytes for Julian day and 6 bytes for nanoseconds within the day.

This does not conform to any parquet [logical type](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md). The schema in the parquet file does not, then, give an indication of the column being anything but an integer.

My question is, how does Spark know to load such a column as a timestamp as opposed to a big integer?

Comment: Actually it's 8 + 4 bytes, not 6 + 6. There is a pull request to document this type, see https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/pull/49.

Comment: Quite right, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Semantics is determined based on the metadata. We'll need some imports:

```scala
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
```

example data:

```scala
val path = "/tmp/ts"

Seq((1, "2017-03-06 10:00:00")).toDF("id", "ts")
  .withColumn("ts", $"ts".cast("timestamp"))
  .write.mode("overwrite").parquet(path)
```

and Hadoop configuration:

```scala
val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
```

Now we can access Spark metadata:

```scala
ParquetFileReader
  .readAllFootersInParallel(conf, fs.getFileStatus(new Path(path)))
  .get(0)
  .getParquetMetadata
  .getFileMetaData
  .getKeyValueMetaData
  .get("org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata")
```

and the result is:

```
String = {"type":"struct","fields: [
  {"name":"id","type":"integer","nullable":false,"metadata":{}},
  {"name":"ts","type":"timestamp","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}
```

Equivalent information can be stored in the Metastore as well.

According to the official documentation this is used to achieve compatibility with Hive and Impala:

> Some Parquet-producing systems, in particular Impala and Hive, store Timestamp into INT96. This flag tells Spark SQL to interpret INT96 data as a timestamp to provide compatibility with these systems.

and can be controlled using `spark.sql.parquet.int96AsTimestamp` property.

Comment: How can I write a INT96 timestamp type? (using `org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter`)  -- I posted a SO question for this, but am lost and hope you can assist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657496/how-to-write-timestamp-logical-type-int96-to-parquet-using-parquetwriter

Comment: @JamesWierzba TBH I've never gave the exact procedure much thought. Though if you follow the [relevant code from the Spark's Parquet writer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d66a4e82eceb89a274edeb22c2fb4384bed5078b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetWriteSupport.scala#L171-L178) you should get all the required details.