# Why is casting from long to date not allowed in spark?

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, timestamp

In Spark you can cast a `LongType` without issues to `TimestampType`. And after that there are no issues casting a `TimestampType` to a `DateType`.

The flow

```
long -> timestamp -> date
```

therefor is possible. However, it is not possible to cast a `LongType` directly to `DateType`.
So

```
long -> date
```

is not allowed.

Internally a `TimestampType` is just a `long` and a `DateType` is just an `int`.

Thus...

```
long -> long -> int // this is fine
long -> int // this is not fine
```

Why is that? Why doesn't spark allow casting to a `date` directly from a `long`?

Comment: Ambiguity for starters. Furthermore internal representation doesn't reflect external one (timestamp has millisecond precision, while long during casting is interpreted as seconds).

Comment: So why does casting from long to timestamp cause no problems? Sure, timestamp has millisecond precision, date has day precision. But a long is just a long. So whatever the long is casted to, there must be some kind of explicit conversion... why isn't there one for `long -> date` since it's inherently still a loss of information, regardless if `timestamp` is in between?

Comment: If you're looking for a strict reason why it cannot be done I don't think there is one. Effectively we have well established conventions of representing timestamps in (milli)seconds but not such thing for days. Ambiguity is a problem as well - should we interpret integer as (milli)seconds or days? You can also check http://stackoverflow.com/q/42628287/1560062 to see that internal representation is not that relevant since internally it won't be used directly anyway.

Answer (score -2):

```
val DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT: String = "yyyy-MM-dd"
val unixDate: Date = new Date(if (ts > Int.MaxValue) ts else ts * 1000)
val dateFormatter: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT)
val date: String = dateFormatter.format(unixDate)
```