# How to write TIMESTAMP logical type (INT96) to parquet, using ParquetWriter?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, parquet

I have a tool that uses a [org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetWriter.java) to convert CSV data files to parquet data files.

Currently, it only handles `int32`, `double`, and `string`

I need to support the parquet `timestamp` logical type (annotated as int96), and I am lost on how to do that because I can't find a precise specification online.

It appears this timestamp encoding (int96) is rare and not well supported. I've found very little specification details online. [This github README](https://github.com/xhochy/parquet-format/blob/cb4727767823ae201fd567f67825cc22834c20e9/LogicalTypes.md#int96-timestamps-also-called-impala_timestamp) states that:

> Timestamps saved as an int96 are made up of the nanoseconds in the day
>   (first 8 byte) and the Julian day (last 4 bytes).

**Specifically:**

1. Which parquet [Type](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-column/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/schema/Type.java) do I use for the column in [MessageType](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-column/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/schema/MessageType.java) schema? I assume I should use the primitive type, `PrimitiveTypeName.INT96`, but I'm not sure if there may be a way to specify a logical type?
2. How do I write the data? i.e. In what format do I write the timestamp to the group? For an INT96 timestamp, I assume I must write some binary type?

Here is a simplified version of my code that demonstrates what I am trying to do. Specifically, take a look at the "TODO" comments, these are the two points in the code that correlate to the questions above.

```
List<Type> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add(new PrimitiveType(Type.Repetition.OPTIONAL, PrimitiveTypeName.INT32, "int32_col", null));
fields.add(new PrimitiveType(Type.Repetition.OPTIONAL, PrimitiveTypeName.DOUBLE, "double_col", null));
fields.add(new PrimitiveType(Type.Repetition.OPTIONAL, PrimitiveTypeName.STRING, "string_col", null));

// TODO: 
//   Specify the TIMESTAMP type. 
//   How? INT96 primitive type? Is there a logical timestamp type I can use w/ MessageType schema?
fields.add(new PrimitiveType(Type.Repetition.OPTIONAL, PrimitiveTypeName.INT96, "timestamp_col", null)); 

MessageType schema = new MessageType("input", fields);

// initialize writer
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setQuietMode(true);
GroupWriteSupport.setSchema(schema, configuration);
ParquetWriter<Group> writer = new ParquetWriter<Group>(
  new Path("output.parquet"),
  new GroupWriteSupport(),
  CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY,
  ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE,
  ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,
  1048576,
  true,
  false,
  ParquetProperties.WriterVersion.PARQUET_1_0,
  configuration
);

// write CSV data
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(new File(csv), StandardCharsets.UTF_8, CSVFormat.TDF.withQuote(null));
ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<>(schemaMap.keySet());
int colIndex;
int rowNum = 0;
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
  rowNum ++;
  Group group = f.newGroup();
  colIndex = 0;
  for (String record : csvRecord) {
    if (record == null || record.isEmpty() || record.equals( "NULL")) {
      colIndex++;
      continue;
    }


    record = record.trim();
    String type = schemaMap.get(columns.get(colIndex)).get("type").toString();
    MessageTypeConverter.addTypeValueToGroup(type, record, group, colIndex++);

    switch (colIndex) {
      case 0: // int32
        group.add(colIndex, Integer.parseInt(record));
        break;
      case 1: // double
        group.add(colIndex, Double.parseDouble(record));
        break;
      case 2: // string
        group.add(colIndex, record);
        break;
      case 3:
        // TODO: convert CSV string value to TIMESTAMP type (how?)
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
  writer.write(group);
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: FYI, it looks like `INT96` support is deprecated in Parquet from what I read in [this issue ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-323).

Comment: @BasilBourque Yeah, I saw that. Unfortunately the consumer of the parquet files is enforcing this 96 bit timestamp encoding, so I need to figure out how to write this type.

Comment: I do not know anything about Parquet or Hadoop, so I cannot post an Answer. But some tips that might help: Java primitives are limited to 64-bits for numbers, so use `BigInteger` class to manage a 96-bit number. The `Instant` class, and other *java.time* classes have nanosecond resolution. But they work internally by tracking a pair of numbers: a number of whole seconds since epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z plus a number of nanoseconds for the fractional second. So you will have to do a bit of math to feed your total elapsed nanos into a pair of numbers. See `Instant.ofEpochSecond` & `.plusNanos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, using [this code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d66a4e82eceb89a274edeb22c2fb4384bed5078b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetWriteSupport.scala#L171-L178) from spark sql as a reference.

The INT96 binary encoding is split into 2 parts:
First 8 bytes are nanoseconds since midnight
Last 4 bytes is [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)

```
String value = "2019-02-13 13:35:05";

final long NANOS_PER_HOUR = TimeUnit.HOURS.toNanos(1);
final long NANOS_PER_MINUTE = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos(1);
final long NANOS_PER_SECOND = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1);

// Parse date
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.setTime(parser.parse(value));

// Calculate Julian days and nanoseconds in the day
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.of(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
int julianDays = (int) JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY.getFrom(dt);
long nanos = (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * NANOS_PER_HOUR)
        + (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * NANOS_PER_MINUTE)
        + (cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) * NANOS_PER_SECOND);

// Write INT96 timestamp
byte[] timestampBuffer = new byte[12];
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(timestampBuffer);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putLong(nanos).putInt(julianDays);

// This is the properly encoded INT96 timestamp
Binary tsValue = Binary.fromReusedByteArray(timestampBuffer);
```

Comment: NanoTime could be used if you have julianDays and nanos instead of packing your own binary.

Answer (score 7):

1. INT96 timestamps use the INT96 physical type without any logical type, so don't annotate them with anything.
2. If you are interested in the structure of an INT96 timestamp, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53104516/5613485). If you would like to see sample code that converts to and from this format, take a look at [this file from Hive](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-2.0/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/parquet/timestamp/NanoTimeUtils.java).

Comment: This is great, I will test this code and see if it works

Comment: I also found this: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d66a4e82eceb89a274edeb22c2fb4384bed5078b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetWriteSupport.scala#L171-L178 -- scala code for encoding int96 timestamp

Comment: No one should not be writing timestamps using INT96. There are documented and supported timestamp types. Use those instead.

Comment: @blue The OP is aware of that. He wrote: "Unfortunately the consumer of the parquet files is enforcing this 96 bit timestamp encoding, so I need to figure out how to write this type."

Comment: I ran into another similar issue, but for writing `null` values. Any chance you could take a look at my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247724/how-can-i-write-null-value-to-parquet-using-org-apache-parquet-hadoop-parquetwri

Comment: I had to convert from a base64 encoded version of this INT96 timestamp to an ISO8601 formatted string. I ended up writing this with the help of this answer. Thanks @Zoltan - https://gist.github.com/marklap/133f1dbd51113de460475321b467aa70

Answer (score 0):

For those using `AvroParquetWriter` and want to write INT96 **physical type** you can use

```
final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setStrings(WRITE_FIXED_AS_INT96,  "field_name");
```

and pass this configuration when building the `AvroParquetWriter`. Your avro schema has to be type `fixed` for `field_name` and type similar to:

```
"type":[
        "null",
        {
               "type":"fixed",
               "name":"INT96",
               "doc":"INT96 represented as byte[12]",
               "size":12
        }
]
```

Full example:

```
final String avroSchemaString = "{\n" +
        "   \"type\":\"record\",\n" +
        "   \"name\":\"userInfo\",\n" +
        "   \"namespace\":\"my.example\",\n" +
        "   \"fields\":[\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "         \"name\":\"date_of_birth\",\n" +
        "         \"type\":[\n" +
        "            \"null\",\n" +
        "            {\n" +
        "               \"type\":\"fixed\",\n" +
        "               \"name\":\"INT96\",\n" +
        "               \"doc\":\"INT96 represented as byte[12]\",\n" +
        "               \"size\":12\n" +
        "            }\n" +
        "         ]\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "   ]\n" +
        "}";
System.out.println("AvroSchema: " + avroSchemaString);

final Schema avroSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(avroSchemaString);
System.out.println("Parsed AvroSchema: " + avroSchema);

final Path outputPath = new Path("/tmp/temp.parquet");
final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
// Comment this line and it will write as FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY of size 12
conf.setStrings(WRITE_FIXED_AS_INT96,  "date_of_birth");


final ParquetWriter<GenericData.Record> parquetWriter = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericData
                .Record>builder(outputPath)
        .withSchema(avroSchema)
        .withConf(conf)
        .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
        .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE)
        .build();
final GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema);

// Convert LocalDate to NanoTime or LocalDateTime to NanoTime
final LocalDate dateToday = LocalDate.now();
final NanoTime nanoTime = new NanoTime((int)JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY.getFrom(dateToday), 0L);
byte[] timestampBuffer = nanoTime.toBinary().getBytes();

// Should be 12
System.out.println(timestampBuffer.length);

GenericData.Fixed fixed = new GenericData.Fixed(avroSchema.getFields().get(0).schema(), timestampBuffer);
record.put("date_of_birth", fixed);
parquetWriter.write(record);

// Close the writer to flush records
parquetWriter.close();
```

It only works for version `1.12.3` of `parquet-avro`. GAV for that:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```