# parquet int96 timestamp conversion to datetime/date via python

Tags: python, apache-spark, casting, timestamp, parquet

## TL;DR

I'd like to **convert an int96 value such as ACIE4NxJAAAKhSUA** into a *readable* timestamp format like **2020-03-02 14:34:22** or whatever that could be normally interpreted...I mostly use python so I'm looking to build a function that does this conversion.  If there's another function that can do the reverse -- even better.

## Background

I'm using parquet-tools to convert a raw parquet file (with snappy compression) to raw JSON via this commmand:

```
C:\Research> java -jar parquet-tools-1.8.2.jar cat --json original-file.snappy.parquet > parquet-output.json
```

Inside the JSON, I'm seeing these values as the timestamps:

```
{... "_id":"101836","timestamp":"ACIE4NxJAAAKhSUA"}
```

I've determined that the timestamp value of "ACIE4NxJAAAKhSUA" is really int96 (this is also confirmed with reading the schema of the parquet file too....

```
message spark_schema {
 ...(stuff)...
  optional binary _id (UTF8);
  optional int96 timestamp;
}
```

I think this is also known as Impala Timestamp as well (at least that's what I've gathered)

## Further Issue Research

I've been searching everywhere for some function or info regarding how to "read" the int96 value (into python -- I'd like to keep it in that language since I'm most familiar with it) and output the timestamp -- I've found nothing.

Here's a very articles I've already looked into (that's related to this subject):

- ParquetWriter research in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657496/how-to-write-timestamp-logical-type-int96-to-parquet-using-parquetwriter)
- Casting int96 via golan in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103762/cast-int96-timestamp-from-parquet-to-golang) NOTE: this has a function that I could explore but I'm not sure how to dive in too deep

## Regarding the depreciated int96 timestamp

Please don't ask me to stop using an old/depreciated timestamp format within a parquet file, I'm well aware of that with the research I've done so far.  I'm a receiver of the file/data -- I can't change the format used on creation.

If there's another way to control the initial JSON output to deliver a "non int96" value -- I'd be interested in that as well.

Thanks so much for your help SO community!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

parquet-tools will not be able to change format type from INT96 to INT64. What you are observing in json output is a String representation of the timestamp stored in INT96 TimestampType. You will need spark to re-write this parquet with timestamp in INT64 TimestampType and then the json output will produce a timestamp (in the format you desire).

You will need to set a specific config in Spark -

```
spark-shell --conf spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType=TIMESTAMP_MICROS

2020-03-16 11:37:50 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.0.20:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1584383875924).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0
      /_/
Using Scala version 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

val sourceDf = spark.read.parquet("original-file.snappy.parquet")
2020-03-16 11:38:31 WARN  Utils:66 - Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
sourceDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [application: struct<name: string, upgrades: struct<value: double> ... 3 more fields>, timestamp: timestamp ... 16 more fields]

scala> sourceDf.repartition(1).write.parquet("Downloads/output")
```

Parquet-tools will show the correct TimestampType

```
parquet-tools schema Downloads/output/part-00000-edba239b-e696-4b4e-8fd3-c7cca9eea6bf-c000.snappy.parquet 

message spark_schema {
  ...
  optional binary _id (UTF8);
  optional int64 timestamp (TIMESTAMP_MICROS);
  ...
}
```

And the json dump gives -

```
parquet-tools cat --json Downloads/output/part-00000-edba239b-e696-4b4e-8fd3-c7cca9eea6bf-c000.snappy.parquet

{..."_id":"101836", "timestamp":1583973827000000}
```

The timestamp recorded is in nano seconds. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much -- this is extremely helpful!  This work exactly as you mentioned.  I was curious if there's a function [within python/some parquet-python-lib] to interpret the String representation (what's seen in the original JSON) and know how to back that into INT64 or timestamp_micros epoch....Thank you again!

Comment: Doug, the code in arrow/cpp/src/parquet/types.h might help:

Comment: One small addition to nice solution. The configuration of parquet can also change within the spark shell, after its instantiation with: `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType", "TIMESTAMP_MICROS")`

Answer (score 1):

Doug, this code from arrow/cpp/src/parquet/types.h shows how the Int96 timestamps are stored internally:

```cpp
constexpr int64_t kJulianToUnixEpochDays = INT64_C(2440588);
constexpr int64_t kSecondsPerDay = INT64_C(60 * 60 * 24);
constexpr int64_t kMillisecondsPerDay = kSecondsPerDay * INT64_C(1000);
constexpr int64_t kMicrosecondsPerDay = kMillisecondsPerDay * INT64_C(1000);
constexpr int64_t kNanosecondsPerDay = kMicrosecondsPerDay * INT64_C(1000);

MANUALLY_ALIGNED_STRUCT(1) Int96 { uint32_t value[3]; };
STRUCT_END(Int96, 12);

static inline void Int96SetNanoSeconds(parquet::Int96& i96, int64_t nanoseconds) {
  std::memcpy(&i96.value, &nanoseconds, sizeof(nanoseconds));
}

static inline int64_t Int96GetNanoSeconds(const parquet::Int96& i96) {
  // We do the computations in the unsigned domain to avoid unsigned behaviour
  // on overflow.
  uint64_t days_since_epoch =
      i96.value[2] - static_cast<uint64_t>(kJulianToUnixEpochDays);
  uint64_t nanoseconds = 0;

  memcpy(&nanoseconds, &i96.value, sizeof(uint64_t));
  return static_cast<int64_t>(days_since_epoch * kNanosecondsPerDay + nanoseconds);
}
```