# Unknown date data type (spark,parquet) [13 character long]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a parquet file with the date column filled with a data type I am having trouble with

[image]

I understand that Hive and Impala tend to rebase their time stamp...However, I cannot seem to convert or find any pointers on how to solve this.

I have tried setting int96RebaseModeInRead and datetimeRebaseModeInRead mode to legacy

I also tried to apply a date schema onto the read operation but to no avail.

[image]

This is with schema applied

[image]

[image]

These are the documentations I've reviewed so far. Maybe there's a simple solution I am not seeing. Let's also assume that there's no way for me to ask the person who created the source file what the heck they did.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#data-source-option

https://kontext.tech/article/1062/spark-2x-to-3x-date-timestamp-and-int96-rebase-modes

https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.1/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-timestamp-compatibility-parquet.html

Also, this thread is the only one I was able to find that shows how the timestamp is created but not how to reverse it. Please give me some pointers.
[parquet int96 timestamp conversion to datetime/date via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698056/parquet-int96-timestamp-conversion-to-datetime-date-via-python)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, great that you're asking questions! Please don't upload images of code/data/errors. There are many reasons why: you can read them [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). If you edit your question to fix this I'm sure you'll get answers more quickly!

Comment: I will go back and edit everything so that it's code instead of pictures afterwork. Thank you for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you try to cast order_date column to  dateType. If thats the case following code could help.
You can read order_date column as stringType from source file and you should use your own timezone for from_utc_timestamp method.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_utc_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

d = ['1374710400000']
df = spark.createDataFrame(d, StringType())
df.show()


df = df.withColumn('new_date',from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(df.value/1000,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),'GMT+1')).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------+
|        value|
+-------------+
|1374710400000|
+-------------+

+-------------+-------------------+
|        value|         new_date|
+-------------+-------------------+
|1374710400000|2013-07-25 13:00:00|
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Wow...thank you so much. This really helped! I will try to apply the entire data frame